# Troubleshooting Google Drive API Issue: Google cloud python function Fails to Detect PDF Files in Shared Folder

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I developed a Python script that operates on the Google Cloud Platform. The script utilizes the Google Drive API and Google Sheet API to access a folder in Google Drive belong to a company , extract data from PDF files within that folder, and then transfer the extracted data to a Google Sheet.

To ensure proper functionality, I set up a service account and configured the necessary APIs. Additionally, I integrated a secret manager to link the function with Google Drive and Google Sheet.

I granted access to the drive folders by sharing them with the service account's email ID.

However, upon running the script, the Drive API failed to detect the PDF files within the shared folders. Surprisingly, the APIs did not return any error messages.

```
def list_files_in_folder(drive,folder_id):
  #print(folder_id)
  # List files in the specified folder
  query = f"parents = '{folder_id}'"
  files = []
  response = drive.files().list(q = query).execute()
  #print(f'response:{response}')
  files = response.get('files')
  #print(f'First page files: {files}')
  next_page_token = response.get('nextPageToken')

  while next_page_token:
    response = drive.files().list(q=query,nextPageToken=next_page_token).execute()
    files.extend(response.get('files'))
    next_page_token = response.get('nextPageToken')

  return files
```

In an attempt to troubleshoot the issue, I tested the script using an alternate Google Drive account, distinct from the company's original drive primary drive, which is accessed by multiple accounts. When I created a folder containing PDF files and shared it with the same service email ID, the script successfully accessed the folder contents without any errors.

Comment: First, I apologize that I cannot imagine your actual situation from your question because of my poor English skill. About `Shared Folder`, where is it? If the folder is included in a Google Drive of the user's account, your script works when the administrator permits to access it by the service account. If the folder is included in a shared Drive, your script doesn't work even when the administrator permits to access it by the service account because of an issue of your current script. First, I would like to correctly understand your situation. I apologize for this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I meant the folder in Google Drive for the company account that I shared with the client email in the service account

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I meant the folder in Google Drive for the company account that I shared with the client email in the service account`. Your reply says that in your situation, you are not using the shared drive. Is my understanding correct? I wanted to confirm whether your situation is due to the shared drive.

Comment: Thank you,I'm sorry for the late reply, I'm using a shared drive

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that you use a shared drive. So, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `I'm using a shared drive`, in this case, your script is required to be modified. So, please modify it as follows and test it again.

#### Modified script:

```py
def list_files_in_folder(drive, folder_id):
    # print(folder_id)
    # List files in the specified folder
    query = f"'{folder_id}' in parents and trashed=false"
    files = []
    response = drive.files().list(
        q=query,
        pageSize=1000,
        supportsAllDrives=True,
        includeItemsFromAllDrives=True,
        corpora="allDrives"
    ).execute()
    # print(f'response:{response}')
    files = response.get('files')
    # print(f'First page files: {files}')
    next_page_token = response.get('nextPageToken')

    while next_page_token:
        response = drive.files().list(
            q=query,
            pageSize=1000,
            nextPageToken=next_page_token,
            supportsAllDrives=True,
            includeItemsFromAllDrives=True,
            corpora="allDrives"
        ).execute()
        files.extend(response.get('files'))
        next_page_token = response.get('nextPageToken')

    return files
```

- When this modified script was run, I confirmed that the file list could be retrieved from the shared drive.

#### Note:

- About your search query of `query = f"parents = '{folder_id}'"`, in order to retrieve the file list under the specific folder, the official document says `'1234567' in parents`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files#examples) But, in [my report](https://tanaikech.github.io/2021/04/27/specification-of-search-query-for-file-list-method-in-drive-api/), in the current stage, `'###folderId###' in parents`, `parents = '###folderId###'`, and `parents in '###folderId###'` can be used for retrieving the file list from the folder. In this modification, I used `'###folderId###' in parents` of the official document.
- Also, in order to avoid retrieving the files in the trash box, I added `trashed=false`.

#### Reference:

- [Method: files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/list)

Comment: thank you very much,it works, I meet another problem when creating a folder in the shared drive, I receive the error message file not found with parent folder ID

Comment: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?alt=json returned "File not found: parentdfoldername.". Details: "[{'message': 'File not found: parentdfoldername', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'notFound', 'location': 'fileId', 'locationType': 'parameter'}]">

Comment: @MKROSTM Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `I meet another problem when creating a folder in the shared drive, I receive the error message file not found with parent folder ID`, I would like to support you. So, can you post it as a new question by including your current script? By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Your search query is wrong

```
parents in '10krlloIS2i_2u_ewkdv3_1NqcpmWSL1w'
```

Not equal

Comment: thank you vert much,still can't read the content of the folder on the shared drive